# How to import an ASP.NET MVC app from VisualStudio to SharpDevelop?

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-2, sharpdevelop

I'd like to import an ASP.NET MVC 2 app from Visual Studio 2008 to SharpDevelop v4.0.

I'm using:
* Windows 7
* IIS 7.5
* .net SDK v4.0
* VisualStudio 2008
* MVC 2
* SharpDevelop v4.0 Beta r6767

Thanks a bunch beforehand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there's [no tooling support](http://community.sharpdevelop.net/forums/t/7872.aspx) in #develop for ASP.NET MVC so don't expect `Add View`, `Add Controller`, `jump to the corresponding view from a controller action` and stuff like this. You could work with ASP.NET projects in #develop using [this plugin](http://sharpdaspnetaddin.codeplex.com/). Because it uses MSBuild you won't have problems compiling an ASP.NET MVC application.